# Help in this proof in Lang's Algebra book

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand this part of the proof:

[image]

I didn't understand why not all coefficients of $f_2,\ldots,f_n$ can lie in the maximal ideal, maybe I'm forgetting something, it should be a very easy thing, but I couldn't understand why, even though it's an doubt in elementary abstract algebra.

I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f_2,\dots,f_n\in\mathfrak m[x]$. From $\sum_{i=1}^ng_if_i=1$ we get $g_1f_1-1\in\mathfrak m[x]$. Let's write $f_1=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ and $g_1=b_mx^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+b_0$. Then we get $$g_1f_1-1=b_mx^{n+m}+(b_{m-1}+b_ma_{n-1})x^{n+m-1}+\cdots+(b_0+b_1a_{n-1}+\cdots+b_ma_{n-m})x^n+\cdots+(b_0a_0-1).$$ (If $n<m$, then the last term in the coefficient of $x^n$ is $b_na_0$.)

This entails that all the coefficients of $g_1$ belong to $\mathfrak m$ and $b_0a_0-1\in\mathfrak m$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why all the coefficients of $g_1$ belong to $\mathfrak m$ and $b_0a_0-1\in \mathfrak m$?

Comment: your answer seems perfectly right, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Edit:  Oops, I was completely wrong on the definition of unimodular.  Here's a (hopefully) correct answer:

Let $k = \mathfrak{o/m}$ be the residue field.  Then the units in $\frac{\mathfrak o[x]}{\mathfrak m[x]} \simeq k[x]$ are the nonzero constant polynomials.

If $f_2, \ldots, f_n \in \mathfrak m[x]$ then reducing the relation to $k[x]$ gives $g_1f_1 = 1$ so $f_1$ is a unit.  So $f_1 \in \mathfrak o[x]$ is a constant polynomial, hence $f_1 = 1$ and $f_2 = \cdots = f_n = 0$.  In this case it's trivial that $f$ has the extension property.

As for why they conclude that it's not possible for $f_2, \ldots, f_n$ to have coefficients in $\mathfrak m$, I assume there is an implicit assumption that $d > 0$ and under this assumption $f_1$ a unit in $k[x]$ is a contradiction.

Comment: yes, you're right, then suppose $f_2$ aren't in $\mathfrak m$, why this implies all _coefficients_ of $f_2$ aren't in $\mathfrak m$ neither?

Comment: In fact, Unimodular means just the $(f_1,\ldots,f_n)=(1)$, you assume what we want to prove which is $f$ has the unimodular extension property, i.e., the first row is $f$

Comment: @user42912: Oops, I've edited it to a different answer.

Comment: Then it's possible to have all coefficients of $f_2,\ldots f_n$? your reasoning seems perfectly fine, but I thought it's impossible. See for example this link: http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~kvshud/Quillen_Suslin.pdf (pages 10-11)

Comment: Another example, see the another answer to this post

Comment: @user42912: As I say in the last paragraph, it's only impossible if you assume $f_1$ has positive degree.  If you allow $f_1$ to be constant then let $(f_1, \ldots, f_n) = (g_1, \ldots, g_n) = (1, 0, \ldots, 0)$.  Then we obviously have $\sum_ig_if_i = 1$ and $f_2, \ldots, f_n \in \mathfrak m[x]$.  If you read the other answer carefully you'll see that you only get a contradiction if you assume that $f_1g_1$ has positive degree.

Comment: yes, you're right, I'm sorry I was so focused in the proof that I misread the last paragraph. Speaking of this, I think $f_1$ has positive degree because the author says $\deg f_i\lt d=\deg f_1$